# Should static files be saved as TXT or CFM or HTML?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

We have a process that creates tens of thousands of static files. Each file is created from a query that takes a few seconds to run. The data in each file changes weekly. These files are served about 500,000 times per day. So, it seems that it would be really beneficial to name, and store, and retrieve these files as efficiently as possible.

Currently, the files are named like this:

```
123-111-1.htm
123-112-1.htm
123-113-1.htm
456-111-2.htm
456-112-2.htm
456-133-2.htm
```

In the files are plain old HTML menus. There is nothing processed in this page. In reality, there might be fifty links.

```
<h1>Company Name</h1>
<ul>
   <li><a href="index.cfm">some link</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.cfm">some link</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.cfm">some link</a></li>
   <li><a href="index.cfm">some link</a></li>
</ul>
```

We include the menu like this:

```
<cfset FileToInclude = "#var1#-#var2#-#var3.htm">
<cfinclude template="#FileToInclude#">
```

My real question is, is there going to be a difference between saving the file as txt, or html, or cfm? With a different file extension, will it be processed by the server differently? If it has a txt extension, will ColdFusion completely ignore it and not cache it? If it has the an html extension, will it not be processed but be cached?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's see what each of the options entail

**txt**

```
 <cfinclude template="#FileToInclude#.txt">
```

We know that the content is not plain text, so this file extension would would not be descriptive of its content. You could configure your webserver to not display `.txt` files. Within, ColdFusion will process it as if it had tags, which may not be what you are expecting.

**html**

```
   <cfinclude template="#FileToInclude#.html">
```

This is more descriptive of the content. The webserver will most likely try to display it. Within ColdFusion will process it as if it had tags which may not be what you are expecting

**cfm**

```
   <cfinclude template="#FileToInclude#.cfm">
```

This is descriptive of what is really running. You can make sure that it never runs as a stand alone file. Because it has a `.cfm` extension, you will be expect it to be processed by ColdFusion.

As for caching, I think ColdFusion caches them all the same.

**db**

You should also consider storing the data in a db

```
 <cfquery name="qryMenu" cachedwithin="#CreateTimeSpan(0, 6, 0, 0)#">
     SELECT menu
     FROM dbo.menu
     WHERE section1 = <cfqueryparam value = "#section1#" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer">
     AND section2 = <cfqueryparam value = "#section2#" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer">
     AND section3 = <cfqueryparam value = "#section3#" cfsqltype = "cf_sql_integer">
 </cfquery>

 <cfoutput query="qryMenu">#menu#</cfoutput>
```

This way you don't have to deal with hundreds of menu files. You can control the caching to exactly what you want. And it will probably but less of a load on your server.

Comment: This is a good explination. Just remember that when you use CFINCLUDE ColdFusion will render the file through it's parsing engine. That's  a source of overhead and potential errors unless it's actual intentional CF code.

Comment: If I really had to do this via files, I think I would use `fileread()`

Comment: James, I've considered your DB solution a while back. I've advised it as a good solution, probably the best solution in our case. But the powers that be really like the old fashioned flat file solution. :(

Answer (score 5):

If you include the file, CF will parse, compile and process it. If there's not CFML in the file, this is a waste of time. It will also put the resulting compiled class into server memory, which is another minor consideration, but a consideration nevertheless.

You should name your file for what the content of the file is. These files have HTML in them, so they should have a .html extension.

If you just want to get the file's content on the screen, simply read the file and output it:

```
<cfoutput>#fileRead("/path/to/file")#</cfoutput>
```

As of ColdFusion 11 there is some setting in which files that have other than a .cfm extension are not compiled when they are included, but as of CF10, they *are* compiled.

Comment: On the non compile option, is that something in cfadmin or in `application.cfc`, or both? I might be useful to have a screenshot

Comment: This is my analysis of it from the CF11 prerelease: http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/03/is-adobe-knowingly-leaving-exploits-in.html and http://blog.adamcameron.me/2014/03/coldfusion-11-more-on-this-cfinclude.html. And google (mostly me, as it turns out): https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=allowedextforinclude

Comment: Oh, they've changed the syntax for it: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/New+in+ColdFusion#NewinColdFusion-Restrictions